# Firefox Android Remote Debugger Port Forwarding Fails

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I'm able to connect and interact pages on desktop Firefox from Firefox Android device.

However I'm not able to forward port (such as localhost:3000) to Firefox Android device.

When I click button connect localhost:3000 in the about:debugging page, I get `Connection still pending, check for messages on the target browser`, then `Connection timed out` error.

Then i tried adb.

```
sudo adb forward tcp:6000 tcp:6000
```

I ran adb forward command and then clicked button connect localhost:3000 in the about:debugging, and still same error.

[image]

On MacOS Monterey v12.6

Desktop Firefox Nightly version: 107.0a1 (2022-09-28) (64-bit)

Android Firefox Nightly version: 107.0a1

On Firefox Android Under Settings

```
Remote debugging via USB is enabled
```

On Firefox Android on about:config

```
devtools.debugger.remote-enabled: true
devtools.debugger.remote-port: 6000
devtools.debugger.force-local: true
```

adb

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 33.0.3-8952118
Installed as /opt/homebrew/bin/adb
```

I'm sure this might be a Firefox issue because I'm able to forward port (localhost:3000) to Android Chrome